# Add nodes to polyline at set intervals

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, line, polyline-creation

I have a shapefile polyline which I would like to add nodes to at set intervals along its length.

Is this possible in ArcGIS 10.2 and how would I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many tools on the [ArcScripts](http://arcscripts.arcgis.com/) website that can do this sort of thing. Search for this tool *Create Points on Polylines* or if you want to insert them into the underlying polyline geometry have a look at *Densify_June_2013*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for the densify tool... Select your line segment and run [the densify tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000003000000) to add vertices along the line.

Or you could use the split tool to break it into individual segments. [split](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q8000000zr000000)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tool by [Ian Broad](http://ianbroad.com/about/) @ian. It seems like it would do exactly what you need.
[Create Points on Polylines](http://ianbroad.com/arcgis-toolbox-create-points-polylines-arcpy/)

Additionally, the [arcpy.Polyline().positionAlongLine()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000008000000) method will also generate a point which you can write to a Point feature class, if you are okay with Python scripting.